# Trying to access an instance of user. NoSuchMethod error when widget loads email = null. calling loggedInUser.email

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Im calling a Firebase user email, i want to display user details on the screen. When widget loads, NoSuchMethod error displays and crashes app. Not sure where to go from here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simmanager/constaints.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SettingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingScreenState createState() => _SettingScreenState();
}

class _SettingScreenState extends State<SettingScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;


  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentUser();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Settings'),
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Icon(
          Icons.edit,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: backgroundColor,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                    size: 75.0,
                    color: primaryLight,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        blurRadius: 5.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        spreadRadius: 5.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Name: ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      // TODO: add stream for user details
                      Container(
                        child: Text('Test'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        blurRadius: 5.0,
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        spreadRadius: 5.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Email: ',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      // TODO: add stream for user details
                      Container(
                        child: Text(loggedInUser.email),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building SettingScreen(dirty, state: _SettingScreenState#b9d92):
The getter 'email' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: email

Comment: Update: email displays when app is hot reloaded, but not on 1st build

Comment: The first time build is called, loggedinuser is null because you haven't yet assigned anything to it. That will happen shortly when getcurrentuser finishes. So inside build you have to put logic that can cope with it being null, like: loggedInUser?.email ?? ' '

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to make the build wait unit getcurrentuser finishes?

Comment: Nope. Build can and will be called at any time, so it must cope with not all of its data being available. Typical tactics involve returning a progress indicator until the data is available, which is then replaced with the real display on the next build. Once you understand that concept you can eliminate a bit of boiler plate using, say, FutureBuilder. Of course you will send up with exactly the same requirement to cope with the incomplete future. The reason that build cannot be delayed is that the framework needs to render something to fill the page even if your network lookup etc still going.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your assignment to loggedInUser inside a setState, otherwise the framework won't know to schedule another build to make use of the changed data.

Comment: thank you @RichardHeap. i was banging my head on this

Answer (score -1):

I've passed through it too. The way I managed so that I could fix the error was change the position of auth.currentUser() declaration. You probably have created your Auth auth inside the StatelessWidget.

Try to move the instance of Auth from StatelessWidget to your State, right before your void initState().

Comment: im using a statefullwidget, i moved the auth before the initState(), same error.